# MS Hyper-V Vbox-style 'Host Key' hotkey

Tags: virtualbox, hyper-v, hotkeys

Does Hyper-V have similar feature to the title Oracle VirtualBox HOST KEY (default: `right Ctrl`) that e.g. enables switching opened host windows via `left Ctrl + Tab` when being in full screen mode on guest OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm looking for the same, I just found this: ctr+alt+left_arrow It is not a host key but you don't need to use the mouse to move to your host.

Comment: I think that's as close to the answer as one could get (BTW it works with `use all my monitors` XRDP connection setting as well). Thx a lot!!